# sp.if not working as it should

Tags: smartpy

I am using sp.if in an internal function, then I call it in an entry point, but whatever I enter in sp.if, it always is read as "True". Why? And how to fix it?
My code :

```
def is_something(self, contract):
    sp.if 1 == 2:
        return "Yes"
    sp.else:
        return "No"

@sp.entry_point
def updateSomething(self, params):
    sp.set_type(params, sp.TRecord(_id = sp.TNat, percentage = sp.TNat))
    sp.trace(self.is_something(sp.sender))
```

When the entry point is called, sp.traces writes "Yes" instead of no. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sp.if` gets translated to Michelson IF's, and cannot be used together with meta-programming `e.g. ruturn statements` since meta-programming gets applied before compilation.

**Meta-programming (Applied before compilation, useful for creating contracts with multiple configurations)**

```
if <condition>:
   do stuff...
else:
   do something else...
```

**Applied at runtime**

```
some_var = sp.local("some_var", 0)
sp.if <condition>:
   some_var.value += 1
sp.else:
   some_var.value = 0
```

Example on how to do it: https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmUWSVV6wnkDUF25thYSBPTJqWaATHeDELoQWwgh3ap6DV&k=17f3f11bcd5974c8d408

Feel free to join [SmartPy Telegram](https://t.me/SmartPy_io).

Comment: Extended the initial answer with more descriptive examples.